# C# Search Byte Array inside Process Memory

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, readprocessmemory

I'm developing a little memory scanner for a specific application. When I select a process to scan, the first thing I want to do is to verify that the process is an instance that specific application... and to do this I must find a signature that can be anywhere inside its memory.

Here is my code:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)] 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] 
internal static extern Boolean ReadProcessMemory([In] IntPtr processHandle, [In] IntPtr processAddress, [Out] Byte[] buffer, [In] UInt32 bytesToRead, [Out] out IntPtr bytesRead); 

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)] 
internal static extern UInt32 VirtualQueryEx([In] IntPtr processHandle, [In, Optional] IntPtr processAddress, [Out] out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION buffer, [In] UInt32 bufferSize); 



internal struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION 
{ 
    public static UInt32 Size = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)); 

    public IntPtr BaseAddress; 
    public IntPtr AllocationBase; 
    public AllocationProtect AllocationProtect; 
    public IntPtr RegionSize; 
    public StateEnum State; 
    public AllocationProtect Protect; 
    public TypeEnum lType; 
} 



public void Open() 
{ 
    Byte[] toFind = new Byte[] { 31, 55, 78, 33, 00, 00, 00, 37 }; 
    UInt32 address = 0; 

    do 
    { 
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();

        if (NativeMethods.VirtualQueryEx(m_Process.Handle, (IntPtr)address, out info, NativeMethods.MemoryBasicInformation.Size) == 0)
            break;

        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[(UInt32)info.RegionSize]; 
        IntPtr bytesRead; 

        if (NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(m_Process.Handle, info.BaseAddress, buffer, (UInt32)buffer.Length, out bytesRead)) 
        { 
            if (buffer.Contains(toFind)) // Extension Method 
            {
                m_IsValid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (address == (UInt32)info.BaseAddress + (UInt32)info.RegionSize) 
            break; 

        address = (UInt32)info.BaseAddress + (UInt32)info.RegionSize; 
    } 
    while (address <= 0x7fffffff); 
}
```

The first problem that this method is never reaching completion and it looks like it's endlessly looping (yesterday I let it running for debug purposes for more than one hour without reaching the end). Checking for Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() inside my loop I noticed that sometimes I get an `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (0x0000012B)` after calling `ReadProcessMemory`... is it the possible cause?

Then I also have some questions:

1) Should I call `OpenProcess` before proceeding with the scan loop? I don't think so, right?

2) I would like to make my application both x32 and x64 compatible. What should I change inside my code to be sure it will properly work with both systems (`address` limit, value type of `address`, `RegionSize` cast, ...)?

3) While scanning the process memory in order to find my target byte array, should I check the current `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`'s properties (`AllocationProtect`, `State`, `Protect` and/or `lType`) to see if I can skip `ReadProcessMemory` for the current region because it's not necessary or it can't be read?

4) Is there anything else I can do to optimize the speed of this methos, which is very important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooooooook I solved it. The problem was the way I was trying to read it without using VirtualQueryEx and checking for the memory region protection!